# How to start a pyspark kernel and execute a python script from shell script?

Tags: python, bash, shell, pyspark

I want to write a shell script that will open up a pyspark kernel and then execute a python script on the pyspark kernel ? 
So , usually this is how I do it :

1. Fire the pyspark kernel with a bunch of necessary jars.
2. After the pyspark kernel loads, I execute my python script using the command 
   exec('/path/to/python_script.py')

I am looking to make this automated writing it into the shell script. So , when I run the shell script, it automatically starts the pyspark kernel and then executes the file in the kernel. 
I tried putting both the commands with a pipe on shell script , it still doesnt work. You guys have any thoughts on how else this could be done ? It isn't necessary that this should be done in shell script only. 
Any thoughts/hacks around this one would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

My bash-script is as follows :

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --jars  /jars/agg-1.7.6.jar --py-files /jars/include_this.py  /Users/divyaswaminathan/python/test_python_api.py
```

Comment: Kernel? Like IPython / Jupyter Kernel?

Comment: I meant the pyspark shell. I am sorry about the confusion

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications (Python tab)

Comment: I recommend posting your code, your bash scripts, etc., so we can be of more assistance.

Comment: @KatyaHandler: That is my bash script and assume that "test_python_api.py" is python unittest script for the include_this.py.